# How to effectively resolve bitstream from an array of signal amplitude

Tags: matlab, software-defined-radio

The other day, I asked about how to model a receiver from 1090MHz ADS-B and Mode S signal,  [link to the post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/91534/modeling-1090mhz-receiver-for-aviation-transponder). With the support from Mbaz. I thought that it was not accurate that if I used a Zero-IF SDR to receive the signal, I should model the receiving chain from the baseband. Luckily, I borrowed a PlutoSDR from the school and plugged it into Matlab to see what happened. Then here is what I got:

[image: Received signal from a vector signal generator]

I used a vector signal generator with a carrier of 1090MHz, -85dBm amplitude. The modulated square wave that I set is similar to an ADS-B or Mode S with 1us period and 0.5us duty cycle.

I set the central frequency of 1090MHz, the suggested sample rate is 10MSPS. I wanted to see around 20us of the signal on the time domain to make sure that I get the square wave at the baseband. The result is quite interesting. And, it is time to get the bitstream from the received square waves.

From the received amplitude array, I used a threshold level to determine which one corresponds to "1" and which one corresponds to "0". Because I sample the signal with the sample rate of 10MSPS, which means I should get around 3-5 samples for a pulse. So I decided to count it by the following code

```
threshold = 0.05;
bit = [];
for i=1:1:how_much_sample %how much sample on the plot
     if (abs_samples(i) > threshold) %loop through the array of amplitude
          bit = [bit 1];
     elseif (abs_samples(i) < threshold)
          bit = [bit 0];
     else
          bit = bit;
     end
end

bit_stream = [];
counter = 0;
for j=1:1:how_much_sample
    if (bit(j) == 1)
         if (counter >= 4)
              bit_stream = [bit_stream 1];
              counter = 0;
         else
              counter = counter + 1;
              bit_stream = bit_stream;
         end
    elseif(bit(j) == 0)
         if (counter >= 4)
              bit_stream = [bit_stream 0];
              counter = 0;
         else
              counter = counter + 1;
         end
    else
         bit_stream = bit_stream;
    end
end
```

I got the results from the above picture. However, I think that it is not the right way to retreat the bitstream, because in a real-life situation with a lot of references, I should get a bunch of wrong bits.

So my question is what is the right way to resolve the bitstream from the received amplitude array from the SDR?
Many thanks to the support from you guys